# PostgreSQL database structure help (multiple database, multiple schema)

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql

Im developing a web application. I have Django for my backend and using PostgreSQL for my database. I am not sure if this is the best approach or not but:
I want to create a database for each company and in that database schema for each project within that company.

recommendations?

I want to create a database for each company and in that database schema for each project within that company.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @RichardHuxton I want to know if this is the correct approach. I'm new to development and not sure if this is the best structure. we web application is somewhat like jira in which it has ticketing system, project overview ...etc. since all project would have the same tables in the database Im thinking of creating a different schema for each project. and a database for company that uses the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Something that we do to prevent some difficulties regardig security is having a completely separate environment for each customer.

*Customer A*:
https://a.your-company.com

*Customer B*:
https://b.your-company.com

Every customer then has a separate and fully dedicated environment in the cloud. Based on the URL, the specific backend service is targetted.

I would advise you to look into a way of making things as generic as possible. At my previous company, they made parts client-specific, and after some years of development they threw everything away and started from scratch, with one rule graved on the wall: "No client-specific implementations allowed".

Answer (score -1):

It is possible but complicated to create distinct databases for each company, with schemas for each project within those databases. Although it provides excellent data isolation and security, managing it can be time- and resource-consuming. Depending on your particular needs, take into account alternatives like employing a shared database with row-level security or multi-tenancy frameworks for a more simplified approach.

Comment: One other key advantage of one-database-per-customer is the ability to backup/restore individual customer data with ease. Which is "best" is a design decision and something that you won't be able to get from random people on the internet.